# Retain all columns in original data table when applying a function that returns a data table with multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have a data table.

```r
# Load package
library(data.table)

# Dummy data table
dt <- data.table(foo = letters[1:10], 
                 bar = LETTERS[11:20], 
                 val = 100:109)
```

I'd like to run a function on a column of this data table that returns a data table with multiple columns. Let's say it looks like this:

```r
# Function that returns data table
f <- function(x){
  data.table(stuff = paste0(x, "_stuff"),
             things = paste0("things_", x))
}
```

If I run it on `foo` from the data table, it returns this:

```r
# Returns only columns from function 
dt[, f(foo)]
#>       stuff   things
#>  1: a_stuff things_a
#>  2: b_stuff things_b
#>  3: c_stuff things_c
#>  4: d_stuff things_d
#>  5: e_stuff things_e
#>  6: f_stuff things_f
#>  7: g_stuff things_g
#>  8: h_stuff things_h
#>  9: i_stuff things_i
#> 10: j_stuff things_j
```

Great! Now, I'd like the returned data table to be appended to my original data table. If I wanted to append it to just a few columns from the original data table, I could just name the columns I want to retain like so:

```r
# Returns named column and columns from function
dt[, .(foo, f(foo))]
#>     foo   stuff   things
#>  1:   a a_stuff things_a
#>  2:   b b_stuff things_b
#>  3:   c c_stuff things_c
#>  4:   d d_stuff things_d
#>  5:   e e_stuff things_e
#>  6:   f f_stuff things_f
#>  7:   g g_stuff things_g
#>  8:   h h_stuff things_h
#>  9:   i i_stuff things_i
#> 10:   j j_stuff things_j
```

But, I want to keep *all* columns without having to name them individually. One way would be to use `by`:

```r
# Retains all columns
dt[, f(foo), by = names(dt)]
#>     foo bar val   stuff   things
#>  1:   a   K 100 a_stuff things_a
#>  2:   b   L 101 b_stuff things_b
#>  3:   c   M 102 c_stuff things_c
#>  4:   d   N 103 d_stuff things_d
#>  5:   e   O 104 e_stuff things_e
#>  6:   f   P 105 f_stuff things_f
#>  7:   g   Q 106 g_stuff things_g
#>  8:   h   R 107 h_stuff things_h
#>  9:   i   S 108 i_stuff things_i
#> 10:   j   T 109 j_stuff things_j
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This gives me the desired result for this test case, but clearly this only makes sense if rows are unique.

I've tried to use something like `dt[, .(names(dt), f(foo))]`, but this doesn't work as `names` returns a vector of strings which is then added as a column.

The obvious solution is to use `:=` like so: `dt[, c("One", "Two") := f(foo)]`. This gives the desired result **but** I have to name the added columns myself, whereas I'd like to retain the column names returned by the function.

Another solution might be `cbind(dt, dt[, foo(f)])`, but this seems cludgy.

What is the correct way to achieve this result?

Comment: Why don't you wrap `cbind(dt, dt[, f(foo)])` in a function?

Comment: Sure, I can do that, but I was wondering if there's a canonical data table way of doing this, as it must be a fairly common task.

Comment: Actually, `dt[, c(.SD, f(foo))]` works fine.

Comment: I suggest you answer your own question with a real answer. ``.SD`` is simple and effective.

Comment: @Gainz The downside of that solution, however, is that it doesn't modify in place, like `:=` would.

Comment: @Lyngbakr Yes I agree but beside naming manually each cols in the ``data.table`` code like you already said with ``dt[, c("One", "Two") := f(foo)]`` I don't know how you could proceed without using ``cbind()``.

Comment: there are things like ``dt[, names(f(dt$foo)) := f(foo)][]``that would work but it isn't really what your looking for

Comment: @Gainz Yeah, that would require that `f` is called twice, which isn't optimal.

Comment: If you find a better solution please @myname. ``data.table`` is one of the package I use the most, I would be please to learn something new!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1) Modify `data.table` in the function:

```
f2 <- function(dt){
    cols <- c("stuff", "things")
    dt[, (cols) := lapply(paste0("_", cols), function(x) paste0(foo, x))]
}
f2(dt)
```

2) using NSE:

```
eval(substitute(dt[, (LHS) := RHS], list(RHS={a <- dt[, f(foo)]}, LHS=names(a))))
```

3) Or assign result to a variable and then update by reference similar to what Gainz mentioned in the comments

```
a <- dt[, f(foo)]
dt[, names(a) := a]
```

I prefer option (3).

Comment: Agreed: (3) is the best solution available.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you don't need to do anything with `i` or `by=` in your processing would be to make `dt` an argument to your function and then use `set()` inside your function, as shown below.

```
f <- function(x, dt){
  set(dt, j = "stuff", value = paste0(dt[[x]], "_stuff"))
  set(dt, j = "things", value = paste0("things_", dt[[x]]))
}

f("foo", dt)
```

Output:

```
> dt
    foo bar val   stuff   things
 1:   a   K 100 a_stuff things_a
 2:   b   L 101 b_stuff things_b
 3:   c   M 102 c_stuff things_c
 4:   d   N 103 d_stuff things_d
 5:   e   O 104 e_stuff things_e
 6:   f   P 105 f_stuff things_f
 7:   g   Q 106 g_stuff things_g
 8:   h   R 107 h_stuff things_h
 9:   i   S 108 i_stuff things_i
10:   j   T 109 j_stuff things_j
```